# Outside lookups broke when using DNSMasq on inside AP

Tags: dnsmasq

I have DNSMasq providing DNS and DHCP on 192.168.1.3.  Gateway is 192.168.1.1.  I turned off DHCP on 1.1.

Any clients on the net can't resolve outside hosts...

Clients can't resolve outside addresses properly.

If I add "dhcp-option=6,192.168.3.1" OR "dhcp-option=6,205.x.x.x" to force outside lookups, outside lookups work, but then inside lookups don't work!

Help!

Answer (score 1):

DNSMasq gets its upstream servers from `/etc/resolv.conf` by default - you want to check that file whether these are correct. It should NOT point to localhost.

If you really want that DNS queries on the server go through DNSMasq, then read the manpage on how to use the `--resolv-file` option to give it the upstream server addresses.